# Error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Integer[]

Tags: java, arrays, integer, int

I'm attempting to create a method that will return an index within an array.

```
private static Integer[] day1 = new Integer[6];

public Integer[] getDay1(Integer team) {
      return day1[team];
}
```

When I try to do this, however, it highlights the opening bracket following day1 with this error.

```
Days.java:32: error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Integer[]
  return day1[team];
             ^
```

Any idea why this is? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Because you're not returning an array of Integers, you're returning a single Integer from the array.

Comment: Which do you want to return? An array or an integer?

Comment: Just the single int, and that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return day1[team];` will return the `team`th value of your array. However the return type of your method is Integer[] (array). Change your method to:

```
public Integer getDay1(Integer team) {
      return day1[team];
}
```

Comment: beat me to it by 7 seconds :)

Comment: Mentally kicking myself for not seeing this.

Comment: the exception actually told you what's wrong in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

you are returning an Integer when you have defined your method to return an array or integers, either change to

```
public Integer getDay1(Integer team) {
  return day1[team];
}
```

or

```
public Integer[] getDay1(Integer team) {
  return day1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` is one integer value, `Integer[]` is an array of single `Integer`s. The signature of your `getDay1` method promises an array as return value, but you are actually returning one single element (the one at position `team`).

I assume you are looking for

```
public Integer getDay1(Integer team) {
      return day1[team];
}
```